# Find battery temperature using Arduino Uno or Feather M0

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, battery, adafruit

I want to run my project using battery. I am using Adafruit Feather M0 Bluefruit LE. I want to know can I face any issue with battery temperature and how can I keep a trace on the battery temperature. If somebody knows how to solve this problem if I use Arduino boards please inform. I think same solution can work for Feather M0.

Any HELP would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about hardware, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ONLY solution is to use additional sensor to check the temperature of the battery. There is no other way. P.S. There are batteries which comes with implemented temperature sensor but most of them if not all are really pricey. I hope that help.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan. I think I'll go with another temperature sensor. Can you suggest which one will be the best for this purpose?

Comment: it depends on your budget and how precise do you want the sensor to be. If you don't need something special I suggest you to use DHT11. This sensor is great for the price you pay. The down site is that you have to stick it to the battery.

Comment: I am developing a proper market level product. So I think I'll be needing a reliable one which is precise enough for a long long time.